# How can I save the printed values in Excel?

Tags: python

I am collecting news replies. The collected replies are output, but I want to save them in Excel.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

chromedriver = './chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('https://news.v.daum.net/v/20200418050117350')

loop, count = True, 0
while loop and count < 10:
   try:
      element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
         EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#alex-area > div > div > div > div.cmt_box > div.alex_more > a'))
    )
    more_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        '#alex-area > div > div > div > div.cmt_box > div.alex_more > a')

    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(more_button).perform()
    count = count + 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
except TimeoutException:
    loop = False

data_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#alex-area > div > div > div > div.cmt_box > 
ul.list_comment')
data_list = data_box.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
for comment_item in data_list:
   print(' '.join(comment_item.find_element_by_css_selector('div p').text.split()))
   print()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: you can create a new file in .csv format

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html) to write to excel files.

```
with xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx') as workbook:
   worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
   for comment_item_index in range(len(data_list)):
       data = ' '.join(data_list[comment_item_index].find_element_by_css_selector('div p').text.split())
       worksheet.write(comment_item_index, 0, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

## open a file

```
writer = csv.writer(open('yourfile.csv','w', encoding="utf-8"))
```

## write to the file

```
writer.writerow(the_printed_values)
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing great, you have done right, to write to `excel` file, you have to use the tweak that, from your `python`, you can simply open a `.csv` file and append your replies to it.

Because any excel program can open your `.csv` file in excel. Just try this and then open your `.csv` file in excel opener.

```
with open("data.csv", mode='a') as file:
  for i in range(10): # you print statement
    file.write(','.join(map(str, ["some", i, "anything"])) + '\n' ) # whatever you want to write, for visualizing I just inserted comma separated values.

# in your case ->
# replies = comment_item.find_element_by_css_selector('div p').text.split()
# file.write(','.join(map(str, replies)) + '\n' )
```

With this, you don't have to import any module or install any other library, just do it natively.
Happy coding ;-)